# Discord Music bot error: Skipping extractors execution since zero extractors were registered

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord-bot

I'm building a Discord Bot for Play Youtube musics on my friend's server.
Btw, When I run "node ." everything is ok.. But when I try to insert a command on Discord Server like a URL YouTube video, this error is printed on terminal..

[image]

Play.js file..

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")
const { MessageEmbed, EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js")
const { QueryType, Player } = require("discord-player");
const { YouTubeExtractor } = require("@discord-player/extractor");


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("play")
        .setDescription("play a song from YouTube.")
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName("search")
                .setDescription("Searches for a song and plays it")
                .addStringOption(option =>
                    option.setName("searchterms").setDescription("search keywords").setRequired(true)
                )
        )
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName("playlist")
                .setDescription("Plays a playlist from YT")
                .addStringOption(option => option.setName("url").setDescription("the playlist's url").setRequired(true))
        )
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName("song")
                .setDescription("Plays a single song from YT")
                .addStringOption(option => option.setName("url").setDescription("the song's url").setRequired(true))
        ),


    execute: async ({ client, interaction }) => {
        // Make sure the user is inside a voice channel
        if (!interaction.member.voice.channel) return interaction.reply("You need to be in a Voice Channel to play a song.");

        // Create a play queue for the server
        // const queue = await client.player.createQueue(interaction.guild);
        const queue = await client.player.nodes.create(interaction.guild)

        // Wait until you are connected to the channel
        if (!queue.connection) await queue.connect(interaction.member.voice.channel)

        let embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        

        if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "song") {
            let url = interaction.options.getString("url")
            
            // Search for the song using the discord-player
            const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: YouTubeExtractor.identifier
            })

            // finish if no tracks were found
            if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                return interaction.reply("No results")

            // Add the track to the queue
            const song = result.tracks[0]
            
            await queue.addTrack(song)
            embed
                .setDescription(`**[${song.title}](${song.url})** has been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
                .setFooter({ text: `Duration: ${song.duration}`})

        }
        else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "playlist") {

            // Search for the playlist using the discord-player
            let url = interaction.options.getString("url")
            const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST
            })

            if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                return interaction.reply(`No playlists found with ${url}`)
            
            // Add the tracks to the queue
            const playlist = result.playlist
            await queue.addTracks(result.tracks)
            embed 
                .setDescription(`**${result.tracks.length} songs from [${playlist.title}](${playlist.url})** have been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(playlist.thumbnail)

        } 
        else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "search") {

            // Search for the song using the discord-player
            let url = interaction.options.getString("searchterms")
            const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO
            })

            // finish if no tracks were found
            if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                return interaction.editReply("No results")
            
            // Add the track to the queue
            const song = result.tracks[0]
            await queue.addTrack(song)
            embed
                .setDescription(`**[${song.title}](${song.url})** has been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
                .setFooter({ text: `Duration: ${song.duration}`})
        }

        // Play the song
        if (!queue.playing) await queue.play()
        
        // Respond with the embed containing information about the player
        await interaction.reply({
            embeds: [embed]
        })
    },
}
```

Index.js file

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const {REST} = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { Client, Intents, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { Player } = require("discord-player")

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


const client = new Client({
  intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
         GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, 
         GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
        ]
});


// List of all commands
const commands = [];
client.commands = new Collection();

const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, "commands"); // E:\yt\discord bot\js\intro\commands
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles)
{
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);

    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

// Add the player on the client
client.player = new Player(client, {
    ytdlOptions: {
        quality: "highestaudio",
        highWaterMark: 1 << 25
    },
})


client.on("ready", () => {
    // Get all ids of the servers
    const guild_ids = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id);


    const rest = new REST({version: '9'}).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);
    for (const guildId of guild_ids)
    {
        rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(process.env.CLIENT_ID, guildId), 
            {body: commands})
        .then(() => console.log('Successfully updated commands for guild ' + guildId))
        .catch(console.error);
    }
});

client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
    if(!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
    if(!command) return;

    try
    {
        await command.execute({client, interaction});
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({content: "There was an error executing this command"});
    }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Terminal code:

Successfully updated commands for guild 383020755790725121
Successfully updated commands for guild 1171689059337383956
(node:18658) [NoExtractors] Warning: Skipping extractors execution since zero extractors were registered
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Answer (score 0):

If don't see that you load any extractor thats why its telling you that no extractors are registered to load the default extractors just insert at the top of your play command:

```
player.extractors.loadDefault()
```

Comment: Sorry the silly ask... Where exactly I should write this code on my project?
I tried it on the first line of play.js file.. 
the code crashes.. and the vscode say: "player" is not available should you try "Player" and the new terminal erros appers :(
Btw, that's my source code if you want to check it.... https://github.com/Winntter/Discord-Bot